# How to reduce or remove noise when using an ADC to sample CAN bus

Tags: fpga, adc, noise, xilinx, can

I'm working on a project to sample CAN messages based on a Xilinx Spartan-6 board. I want to get the timing information of CAN messages. The schematic of data acquisition module is shown below.

The module (including AD9226) is working under a clock of 50 MHz.

[image]

#### Subtracter:

Input from CANH minus input from CANL, to get the differential voltage.

#### Comparator:

- If greater than the threshold value, then output dominant ‘0’.
- If lower than the threshold value, then output recessive ‘1’.

The AD module which I choose is [this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-High-Speed-AD9226-12bit-Dual-AD-Module-Development-Board-Expansion-Board-/262430167529) which can be directly connected to the FPGA board.

I linked the final output with one I/O pin of FPGA board so I can observe it by a logic analyzer. It looks good when using the logic analyzer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

But you can notice that there is noise which I don't want.

Here is the result I observed by ChipScope. The sample frequency is 50 MHz.

[image]

[image]

There are so many unwanted transitions.

The ADC module is well-designed and can be directly connected to the FPGA, so I don't expect so much noise from the input.

Is there a way I can remove the noise to improve the situation? Is there a design principle I can follow when using an ADC to sample a signal?

Comment: Why are you using an ADC to sample CANBUS

Comment: why are you using ADC to read a digital signal?

Comment: even worse, why are you using 2 ADC to sample a differential signal? how could this work?

Comment: @JonRB@jsotola Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I want to get the accurate timing info of CAN messages, the physical level, so I don't think the CAN transceiver is good choice. I use the ADC to get the data directly.

Comment: What you're trying to do is perfectly reasonable, effectively making a home-made oscilloscope and they're a popular-enough method for measuring CAN timing. Can I double-check your ADC sample rate. You say 50 MHz - you do mean 50 Msamples/sec and not, e.g., over an SPI interface with a 50 MHz clock?

Comment: @TonyM Hi, my ADC sample rate is 50 Msamples/sec. The sample rate of AD9226 is dependent on the driven clock rate. The clock rate of FPGA I use is also 50MHz. I didn't use SPI interfaec, I just connect the pin of ADC to the 2x20 pin connector of FPGA board.

Comment: @Joe if that is the case... why are you using an ADC... these are digital signals. Use something like a comparator, schmitt trigger etc... or attenuate and take the signals directly into the FPGA and then metaharden

Comment: @Joe. If your going to use an ADC you need to over sample by a factor of 8 or 16 so you can integrate and get clean results. How do you know this is not just Nyquist noise?

Comment: @JonRB Thanks for you advice! yeah, they are digital signals, but I think only the TTL compatible signal can connect directly to the FPGA. By the way, can I implement schmitt trigger in Xilinx? If I add a schmitt trigger after ADC, does this remove the noise?  Thx!

Comment: @Sparky256 Hi, do you mean by averaging of several samples?

Comment: @peufeu yeah.. The AD9226 has both both single-ended and differential input mode. The AD board I use is designed using single-ended mode. I'm not good at modifying the circuit so I just use these two AD9226 as input of CANH and CANL each...

Comment: You can put in Schmitt triggers, they'll do no harm and may help slightly. More importantly though, have you put timing or placement constraints on your firmware design to allow for the reading of a parallel bus at 50 MHz? Otherwise you could be latching in skewed and corrupt data which appears to you as noise. Or are you using someone else's firmware?

Comment: @Joe. What is the maximum sample rate of your oscilloscope?

Comment: @TonyM Hi, firmware? do you mean the AD module? I bought the one online. According to the doc, it can work well at 50Mhz.

Comment: @Sparky256 oscilloscope? do you mean the maximum sample rate of AD? It provide 12-bit accuracy at 65 MSPS data rates according to the datasheet of AD9226 datasheet.

Comment: @Joe. Ok, that means you cannot sample at 400 MHZ and take the average of 8 samples to act as a digital filter.

Comment: @Sparky256 Hi, could you give me some details about over sample by a factor of 8 or 16? I mean, why should  the oversample rate be a factor of 8 or 16? Could you give me some materials that I can read or just some key words? Thx!

Comment: @Joe. Because 8 and 16 are binary multiples of your sample rate, so it is easy to take the sum of 8 samples and divide by 8, etc. It is a running digital average filter.

Comment: Do your two ADCs sample at the exact same time? If they’re sequential, you’ll get artifacts at edges. Also, 50Msample/sec is much slower than a CAN receiver or other digital regime way to process the signal. You’re not going to get more accurate timing info using those ADCs, at least not in that mode.

Comment: Someone designed a digital logic circuit for your FPGA, in VHDL or Verilog, then synthesised it to produce a configuration file, referred to as the firmware. That configuration file is loaded into your FPGA on power-up, to tell it what logic circuit to implement. In light of that, please post answers to my earlier comment. Thanks.

Comment: @TonyM Thanks! I designed myself. The AD9226's all internal conversion cycles are controlled by a single clock input. So I just put a clock driven signal to ADC. I use a  Clock Forwarding technique of Xilinx FPGA to provide a stable and reliable clock driven signal. I don't know if it's enough for high-speed sampling of ADC. Could you give me some advice? Thx!

Comment: @BobJacobsen Hi, I use the same one clock to drive the two ADC. I think they should work paralleled. And I have checked about datasheet of one CAN receiver MCP25625, the Oscillator maximum freq is 25MHz. According to the bit timing specified by CAN protocol, the TIME_QUANTA should no more than 25. I think the 50Msample/sec should be fine but not good. I don't know if my understand is right. Could you pls give me some advice on how to choose the appropriate ADC? Is there any relevant proj you have read that can be referred? Thx!

Comment: So you are sampling on a 500 kbit/s CAN bus (2 µsec bit time)? That would be 100 samples per bit time if it really samples at 50 Msamples/s.

Comment: Does your comparator have [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#Electronic_circuits) or not? Hysteresis or not, what amplitude threshold (corresponding to a voltage) does it use?

Comment: So, again: have you put timing or placement constraints on your firmware design to allow for the reading of a parallel bus at 50 MHz? Otherwise your FPGA could be latching in skewed and corrupt data which appears to you as noise.

Comment: Can you answer our questions?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Hi, thanks so much for your valuable help. Sorry for the delayed response, I'm kind of busy with some other stuffs this week, the deadline is close. The answer is no. I just use a simple comparator with one threshold value, if greater than it, output dominant, and if lower, output recessive value. I don't have relevant background so I even didn't notice that I should add hysteresis mechanism when I design it. I think I can add a schmitt trigger to provide hysteresis, and set the switching thresholds as 10% and 90% of the peak value. Does it work? Thx!

Comment: @TonyM Hi, thanks for your valuable help. Sorry for the delayed response, I'm kind of busy with some other stuffs this week, the deadline is close. I think the answer should be no. I didn't notice that I need to do that. I searched about timing constraints,  I think IODELAY of Xilinx FPGA may help. I haven't gone into details. I'll let you know after I try. Thanks!

Comment: @TonyM Do I understand right by using IODELAY tech to put timing constraints? Thanks!

Comment: @TonyM Hi Tony, thx so much for your detailed reply. I had read Xilinx UG381 about ILOGIC2 and rewritten some code according to the guide. I also replace the connection between ADC and FPGA board with more stable wire. Things look better now, the noise are removed. Look back to this question, it's simple and sort of stupid :) Anyway, thanks for your patient reply, you help me a lot. Maybe you could post an answer if you like and I could accept it. Thx again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your FPGA has input and output DFFs for each pin. Read up on I/O pin DFFs in Xilinx UG381, particularly on the pin input DFF (ILOGIC2) and the programmable input-pin-to-DFF delay path to that DFF (DDLY).

Use these input DFFs on your ADC input data bus pins to latch in the ADC conversion results.

The timing relationships between a pin to its input DFF and its output DFF are fixed for the silicon, varying only with temperature and slightly from part to part. You can adjust their DDLYs to get a clock-to-setup time that accommodates ADC bus timings.

Then you don't need timing constraints and synthesis routing is eased and consistent over builds. This is much simpler.

Make sure your VHDL takes the ADC bus straight into DFFs, with no combinatorial logic between pins and DFFs. Otherwise, the input pin DFFs can't be used because the circuit can't be routed during synthesis.